# How to use core data in background ?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, concurrency

After creating simple code to getting data from CoreData, I realised that some unknown errors are fired. I read that fetching data in background is not that simple. Unfortunately I'm new in iOS developing and only know Swift, where there are many objective-C tutorials for that. 
This is my code:

```
func reloadData() {
    let priority = DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(priority, 0)) {
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext

        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Person")
        do {
            let results = try managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
            let people = results as! [NSManagedObject]
            for person in people {
                collectionViewData.append(person)
            }
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Could not fetch \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            self.collectionView?.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

How to implement this with NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType and stuff like that in Swift?

Comment: Do you need to? Does the fetc take a long time? Why not use a fetched results controller and fetch batch size!

Comment: What do you mean by use fetched results controller and fetch batch size?

Comment: Google fetched results controller (nsfetchedresultscontroller)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code will almost certainly fail. You are accessing your main managed object context from a background thread.

From your code it seems that you do not need a background fetch. Remove all GCD (grand central dispatch) parts of your code and you should be fine.

For reference, this is how you do a background operation in Core Data:

```
let moc = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .PrivateQueueConcurrencyType)
moc.parentContext = <insert main context here>
moc.performBlock {
   // make changes, fetch, save
}
```

After saving, your main context will have the changes. To update a table view, implement `NSFetchedResultsController` and its delegate methods to do it automatically.

Comment: But what can i do if i want to update my Child private context's data with the main context's data?

Comment: I cannot imagine a reasonable use case for this. But you could perhaps do it via `NSNotification`.